# Let $f$ be a real, continuous, twice differentiable function satisfying $f(x)f''(x) \neq 0 \ \forall x $, prove that $f(x)f''(x)>0$.

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

Let $f$ be a real, continuous, twice differentiable function satisfying $f(x)f''(x) \neq 0 \ \forall x $, prove that
$f(x)f''(x)>0$.

I can see why this should be true .

Suppose otherwise, then if $f(x)>0$ implies $f''(x)<0$ and this means the graph is concave downwards and it must continue decreasing after some point without changing concavity and thus $f(x)=0$ giving a contradiction. Similar for other case when $f(x)>0$.

So my question is how to rigorously prove this?

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: $f$ must be defined on all $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe It is not mentioned..I think this is to be assumed.

Comment: "and it must continue decreasing after some point" - This is not necessarily true, so you'll have a hard time actually proving it.  A function with $f''(x) < 0$ might be always increasing too.

Comment: @Brian Moehring... I knew what to prove but I couldn't articulate it. I also get your point. $\ln x$ is an easy example of it.

Comment: I know you already have your answer, but part of your question just struck me as odd.  If a function is [twice] differentiable, then it is continuous, so saying "continuous, twice differentiable" is a bit redundant.  I am wondering if you made a typo and it should be the stronger assumption "continuously twice differentiable" instead.  In truth, it works either way but with a slightly more elementary proof with the stronger condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that $f$ is defined on the whole real line. This is a slight different approach.

We first note that $f$ is not constant and therefore there is $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(a)\not=0$. Moreover, by the intermediate value properties, both $f$ and $f''$ have constant sign over the real line.

If $f(x)>0$ and $f''(x)<0$ then $f$ is strictly concave and the graph of $f$ lies below the tangent line at $a$:
$$f(x)\leq f'(a)(x-a)+f(a)\qquad \tag{*}$$
If $f'(a)<0$ then take the limit as $x\to +\infty$ and it follows that the RHS of (*) goes to $-\infty$ and therefore also $f(x)$ is eventually negative. Contradiction.

Similarly, if $f'(a)>0$ then take the limit as $x\to -\infty$ and it follows that the RHS of (*) goes to $-\infty$ and therefore also $f(x)$ is eventually negative. Contradiction.

Along the same lines, by using concavity, we exclude the case $f(x)<0$ and $f''(x)>0$.

Thus we may conclude that $f$ and $f''$ have the same sign and $f(x)f''(x)>0$.

Comment: You mean "If $f'(a)<0$..."?

Comment: Yes... of course you are correct. I missed a $'$ two times.  Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks , I get it now...

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, it's worthwhile to mention that we are also using also  the intermediate value properties of both $f$, $f′$.

Answer (score 2):

The hypothesis $f(x)f''(x) \neq 0$ implies that $f$ does not vanish, so by continuity, it keeps a constant sign. Let's suppose that for all $x$, one has $f(x) > 0$. Such a function cannot be concave on $\mathbb{R}$, so there exists $x$ such that $f''(x) \geq 0$.

But because $f''$ is a derivative, then by Darboux theorem, it satisfies the intermediate value property. Moreover, $f''$ does not vanish, so $f''$ keeps a constant sign. We deduce that $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x$, and so $f(x) f''(x) > 0$ for all $x$.

The case where $f(x) < 0$ is similar.

Comment: Since OP made an error in their proof sketch of "Such a function cannot be concave on $\mathbb{R}$" we probably shouldn't simply assert it.

Comment: @BrianMoehring If $f$ is concave, it is below all its tangent. If a tangent is not horizontal, then $f$ must take negative values...